# tensorflow.js 2 dimensional input?

Tags: tensorflow, multidimensional-array, neural-network, layer, tensorflow.js

```
const trainingData = tf.tensor3d(fixedData.map(item => 
       
        [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[...],[...],[...]]
))

 model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [4,16],
    activation: "relu",
    units: 4,
  }))
model.compile({
    loss: "meanSquaredError",
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.05),
    metrics: ['accuracy']
  })

  model.fit(trainingData, outputData, {epochs: 10})
  .then((history) => {
    // console.log(history)
    model.predict(testingData).print()

      })
```

Error:
(node:5118) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have 2 dimension(s). but got array with shape 935,4,16.

can the inputShape be 2-dimension?

Comment: `trainingData` is a 3D tensor so use `tf.tensor2d()` instead.

Comment: My code now works only when the output has shape [4,4]. Is the shape of the output dependant on the shape of the input? my output should be in 2d while the input is 3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not provided the complete code. It would be important to see your labels (output) data. I have fake the output data to match the output of your single dense layer.
Also, as @yudhiesh mentioned in the comments, your tensor had just 2 dimensions. I have also fixed that in case you wanna stick with [4,16] for each input.

here is the code running

```
const trainingData = tf.tensor3d( 
         [[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]]]
)

const output = tf.tensor3d( 
        [[ [1,2,3,4],
         [1,2,3,4],
         [1,2,3,4],
         [1,2,3,4]]]
          )

const model = tf.sequential()

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [4, 16],
    activation: "relu",
    units: 4
  }))



model.compile({
    loss: "meanSquaredError",
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.05),
    metrics: ['accuracy']
  })


model.fit(trainingData,output, {epochs: 2})
  .then((history) => {
    model.predict(trainingData).print()
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e.message);
});
```

Comment: this is thhe output: 
const outputData = tf.tensor2d(fixedData.map(item => [ // shape:[ 935, 4 ]
        
    // item.position === 1 ? 1 : 0,
    // item.position !== 1 ? 1 : 0,
    item[1][0] === 1 ? 1 : 0,
    item[1][1] === 1 ? 1 : 0,
    item[1][2] === 1 ? 1 : 0,
    item[1][3] === 1 ? 1 : 0,
    

  ]))

Comment: My code now works only when the output has shape [4,4]. Is the shape of the output dependant on the shape of the input? my output should be in 2d while the input is 3d.

Comment: Your input and output can be anything. I don't know if your input is 3d. I thought you were definying a batch to train. So basically, if you have a trainingData with shape (10,4,16), you have a batch of ten 4x16 tensors.